# Python : How to do conditional rounding in dataframe column values?

Tags: pandas

```
data = {'Name' : ['tom','bul','zack','doll','viru'],'price':[.2012,.05785,2.03,5.89,.029876]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to round to 0 decimal points if the 'price' value is more than 1 and round to 4 decimal points if the value is less than 1. Please suggest.

Comment: `df['price'] = np.where(df.price>1, ..., ...)`?

Comment: Got it. Thanks my friend.

Comment: Quang, any way you could elaborate in the answer section? so you are using numpy in addition to pandas?

Answer (score 0):

If there are many conditions, I prefer using [numpy.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) as in following:

```py
import numpy as np
np.select(
    [df.price >= 1, df.price < 1],
    [df.price.round(0), df.price.round(2)],
)
# df
#    Name     price  price2
# 0   tom  0.201200    0.20
# 1   bul  0.057850    0.06
# 2  zack  2.030000    2.00
# 3  doll  5.890000    6.00
# 4  viru  0.029876    0.03
```

With more conditions, we could do something like this:

```py
df['price3'] = np.select(
    [df.price >= 3, df.price >= 1, df.price < 1],
    [df.price.round(0), df.price.round(2), df.price.round(3)],
)
# df
#    Name     price  price2  price3
# 0   tom  0.201200    0.20   0.201
# 1   bul  0.057850    0.06   0.058
# 2  zack  2.030000    2.00   2.030
# 3  doll  5.890000    6.00   6.000
# 4  viru  0.029876    0.03   0.030
```